# Cannot change the locale settings on Magento installation

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu-14.04

Need to get into Magento shop as a developer, and got some basic trouble on installation.

Background: Got a LUBUNTU Virtual Box running Apache, PHP 5.5 and MySQL. Downloaded magento from http://www.magentocommerce.com/download.

Made a database manually with phpMyAdmin, copied the code of Magento to /var/www/html/magento and chmod'ed it to 775,  chown'ed it to www-data:www-data.

The problem: on startup screen from Magento installation I cannot select another language. After a selection it gets back to English / US. And trying to go through with English causes this error:

```
#0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645):
    Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
    #1 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(407): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-upgrade', '1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.2')
    #2 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(286): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeData('1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.2')
    #3 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
    #4 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(351): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
    #5 /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #6 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #7 {main}
```

Has someone got any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you created a user in the database for magento, with permission to update this database?

Comment: Actually it is before Magento asked me for a database user. The locals selection is the first screen. Cannot change the locals.

Comment: It's been a while since I used magento, but `_modifyResourceDb` really sounds like a function that's trying to update the DB.

Comment: Yeah, but first I am having the problem that I cannot change the locales to german. Cause the DropDown aways gets back to english. Next screens asks me for the DB user. I gave it correctly. But after second screen the exception appears

Comment: This sounds like one of those bugs that is really specific to your setup, I'm not sure it will be possible to figure it out remotely. Maybe you should try just deleting what you have and starting again from scratch, ideally on a different computer but at least in a different folder, just incase there's some configuration (permission, htaccess, whatever) issue that isn't easily visible. You could also try using a livecd, to see how the installation would work in a completely fresh computer.

Comment: Made severel setups, in LUBUNTU, UBUNTU (Server only) and Windows 7 (XAMPP) and Windows 8 (XAMPP)... All the same. Got it running at least, but just with english locales...

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

In my case using "localhost" as hostname(http://localhost/magento) causes the problem.

Using "127.168.1.1"(http://127.168.1.1/magento) solves it.

Comment: For me too... The question is why? Is that normal?